# Segment video with FFMPEG using custom filenames for output

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to segment a video and name the cropped files in a specific way. Right now I'm using

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -f segment -segment_time 59 output_%03d.wav
```

and looping over created files, parsing their filenames and renaming them accordingly.
I have an array which contains

```
array=[1650027545, 1650027300, 1650026502, ...]
```

and want the output files to be in;

```
output_1650027545.wav
output_1650027300.wav
output_1650026502.wav
```

format. Since there's no loop, I can't figure out how to implement such a naming scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entirely forgot my question here. I couldn't find anything related to this problem in the [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) documentation. My solution was to rename the files manually.

```
for index, new_suffix in enumerate(name_array):
    os.rename("output_{:03d}.wav".format(index), "output_{}.wav".format(new_suffix))
```